# VS Code execute current line or selection to in the integrated console

Tags: scala, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, ammonite

This old Emacs user, who is used to elpy, is attempting to move onto VSCode with Scala & more specifically Ammonite repl.

I used Ctrl+' to open the integrated terminal & all I have to do is type amm on the bash shell (ubuntu) to open the repl; however, I still miss being able to send the either the line or selection from the editor to integrated shell with Ctrl+Enter.

I guess this means a bit of coding. Where can I start? Has anyone accomplished similar?

Thanks much,

Comment: Take a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: Aluan: Needs a bit of tweaking at least, but looks promising. At least I should be able to utilize it as a sample. Thanks much,

Answer (score 25):

If you already have your terminal and REPL open, there is a built in command called "Run Selected Text in Active Terminal" / `workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText`.

It has no default keybinding, so you need to set it yourself. Something like this would work:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+enter",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I guess to truly work as elpy. I guess I need to add multiple commands using tasks. 
"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
"commands": "expandLineSelection" & "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText" & "cancelSection"
but this is really good. Thank you

Comment: I just posted Answer to my above added comment Q extended.

Comment: Surprising it doesnt have a `run current line and move cursor to next` short cut(Like f9 in spyder) . Thought its very commonly used shortcut

Comment: I still cannot figure out to send the current line to terminal. I was not able to give multiple commands , I think separating them by & is not the right format. Were you managed to do it?

Answer (score 17):

Actually, I found that adding VSCode [Macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension does the job:

I just changed settings.json:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.fontSize": 11,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 11,
    "macros": {
        "execCurLn": [
            "cursorUp",
            "expandLineSelection",
            "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
            "cancelSelection"
        ]
    }
}
```

and added (1st part is pure @kwood & thank u again) to keybindings.json

```
   {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
            "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
    }
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
          "command": "macros.execCurLn",
            "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
    },
{ "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"},
{ "key": "ctrl+`", "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup", "when": "terminalFocus"}
```

Comment: It results in runing the next line when the mouse focus is in a line, not the current line. selection works.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to insert a new line afterwards if it's the last line in the file?

Comment: @ZhilongJia I edited the answer to add cursorUp to the beginning of the macro. It works but I don't understand why.

Comment: Never mind, the macro runs the next line (when no selection) as soon as you try to run an empty line.

Answer (score 16):

Open the command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and look for `Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal`. On the left you will see the key binding or a wheel engine to set the binding.

[image]

Comment: If you click on that settings icon at the right end of that row, you can edit the 'keybinding', which is the shortcut. In my Ubuntu VSCode there was no default shortcut, so I added it this way.

Answer (score 1):

follow another post [VS Code move to next line on run ctrl + enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404225/vs-code-move-to-next-line-on-run-ctrl-enter), to run current line then cursor down, avoiding running next line unexpectedly

in settings.json, add

```
"macros": {
    "pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown": [
        "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "cursorDown",
    ]
}
```

in keybindings.json, add

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
      "command": "macros.pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
},
```