# How to run a few selected lines of code in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do I execute run Shift + Enter only the selection of highlighted lines of code in vscode?

Edit: Maybe I should be clearer.

when hitting Shift + Enter the following error :

`Unable to initialize device PRN`

but when I right click > run python file in terminal the code works.

Comment: After installing the Python Extension, I believe the shortcut is shift + enter.

Comment: What OS are you developing on? "Unable to initialize device PRN" suggests your pseudo-random number generator isn't up and running when you're doing development and that's causing the failure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode run code selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771589/vscode-run-code-selection)

Answer (score 9):

> Select one or more lines, then press Shift+Enter or right-click and
>   select Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal. This command is
>   convenient for testing just a part of a file.

That is what is on the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for Python and is what works for me. It is `Shift + Enter` not `Ctrl`

Note that this needs the [Python 3 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to be installed.

Answer (score 5):

You can just select the lines and then `right click > Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`.

[image: Mac screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code supports working with Jupyter Notebooks natively, as well as through Python code files

read this article for any

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jupyter extension, then run cells together rather than whole files

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run multiline selction in interactive window make sure the file is interpreted as a python file. If it is not shift+enter will work for single line, but not for multiline selection.