# VS Code Python move to next line on run ctrl + enter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code and running code into the python interactive window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. I would like the cursor to move to the next line automatically so I can go through the code line-by-line.

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm also wondering this. Did you manage to enable it?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As explained in [this blog post](http://actuarialdatascience.com/shortcut_vscode.html), here is how you can make VS Code run code selections using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and move to next line:

```
###############################
# 1. Install extension "macros" in Visual Code
#
# Hit View on top menu
# Search for extension named "macros" (by geddski)
# Install "macros" extension
#
###############################


###############################
# 2. Add code below to keybindings.json
#
# Hit <Ctrl> + <Shift> + <P>
# Enter in search bar: JSON
# Select Open keyboard shortcuts
#
###############################

{
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }


###############################
# 3. Add code below to settings.json
#
# Hit <Ctrl> + <Shift> + <P>
# Enter in search bar: JSON
# Select Open settings 
#
###############################

"macros": {  // Note: this requires macros extension by publisher:"geddski" 
        "pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown": [
            "python.execSelectionInTerminal", 
            "cursorDown" 
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me just after removing a preset shortcut ("editor.action.insertLineAfter") already using ctrl+enter. It was not being overwritten by this keybindings.json nor settings.json.

Comment: How should I adapt the `where` clause if I want to execute selection in notebooks as well?

Comment: To send commands to interactive window rather than the terminal, it worked for me to just change `"python.execSelectionInTerminal"` to `"jupyter.execSelectionInteractive"` and make sure you tick the box in settings `Jupyter: Send Selection To Interactive Window`

Comment: This solution worked for me until vscode updated to Version: 1.84.1. If the line is indented two tabs or more it runs until the end of the indented code. I also took out "cursorDown" in the macro because it would move down two spaces. Highlighting the line and hitting ctrl+enter works, but I cannot have the curser on the line without the highlight and use ctrl+enter if indented two tabs or more.

Answer (score 8):

The framework suggested by P.Marres works for me on the "run and down" part, but it sends commands to the terminal. The below setting helped me to run a `.py` file "line and down" in the interactive window.

prerequisite:

- The macros extension by publisher:"geddski"
- The Jupyter extension (installed by default with the Python extension, replacing the older `python.datascience`)

In keybindings.json, include:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.jupyterExeSelThenCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && isWorkspaceTrusted && jupyter.ownsSelection && !findInputFocussed && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.jupyterRunCellThenCursorDown",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && isWorkspaceTrusted && jupyter.hascodecells && !editorHasSelection && !notebookEditorFocused"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.interactiveExe",
        "when": "resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'"
    }
]
```

In settings.json include:

```
"macros": {  
        "pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown": [
            "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
            "cursorDown"
        ],
        "jupyterExeSelThenCursorDown":[
            "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
            "cursorDown"
        ],
        "jupyterRunCellThenCursorDown":[
            "jupyter.runcurrentcelladvance",
            "cursorDown"
        ],
        "interactiveExe":[
            "interactive.execute",
            "cursorDown"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Why have so many entries? Could you explain why each is needed?

Comment: or you can just tweak slightly P.Marres solution: change `"python.execSelectionInTerminal"` to `"jupyter.execSelectionInteractive"` and make sure you have ticked in settings `Jupyter: Send Selection To Interactive Window`. It is not recommended to have so many entries with the same keybindings, it is very unclear which is doing what and will be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually part of the new default behaviour for versions of the Python extension equal to or greater than [2023.20.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/v2023.20.0). See [Prevent VSCode from skipping to next non empty line when executing current line with Shift+Enter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77521304/11107541) and [related release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_improvements-to-run-line-in-the-terminal) for more info. If you want to disable it, use the `python.REPL.enableREPLSmartSend` setting.

Prior to version 2023.20.0 of the Python extension, for running code in the terminal when there are no code cells (`#%%` cell magic), and running in an interactive windows when there are, as of VS Code 1.74, you can do this as follows using [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) (put this in your keybindings.json file, which you can open with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["python.execSelectionInTerminal", "cursorDown"],
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.hascodecells && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'",
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["jupyter.execSelectionInteractive", "cursorDown"],
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && isWorkspaceTrusted && jupyter.hascodecells && !editorHasSelection && !notebookEditorFocused"
}
```

Though note that in Notebook editors, `notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow` is bound by default to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, and similarly, to `jupyter.runcurrentcelladvance` in a Python file with code cells.

---

Note that this was [raised as a feature-request before](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13495), but it was declined with [the reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13495#issuecomment-697994547):

> Thanks for the suggestion! We talked about it with the team and we have unfortunately decided we will not be moving forward with this idea. We think there isn't an enough widespread need for this to warrant the maintenance cost for the feature.

There's a subsequent re-raising of the request which is still open at the time of this writing: [Go to next line #14695](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14695). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by P.Marres showing [this blog](http://actuarialdatascience.com/shortcut_vscode.html) post's code was great! I needed this for the windows subsystem in linux.

Here is how you would do it for the Windows Subsystem for Linux in Visual Studio Code:

```
###############################
# 1. Install extension "macros" in Visual Code
#
# Hit View on top menu
# Search for extension named "macros" (by geddski)
# Install "macros" extension
#
###############################


###############################
# 2. Add code below to keybindings.json
#
# Hit <Crtl> + <Shift> + <P>
# Enter in search bar: JSON
# Select Open keyboard shortcuts
#
###############################

{
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "macros.ExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
    }


###############################
# 3. Add code below to settings.json
#
# Hit <Crtl> + <Shift> + <P>
# Enter in search bar: JSON
# Select Open settings 
#
###############################

"macros": {  // Note: this requires macros extension by publisher:"geddski" 
            "ExecSelectionAndCursorDown": [
                "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText", 
                "cursorDown" 
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent ctrl + enter to launch a python terminal when you are using a jupyter notebook add resourceExtname parameter to the when clause:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "macros.pythonExecSelectionAndCursorDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python' && resourceExtname == '.py'"
}
```

This will prevent the overwriting of the default jupyter notebook behaviour, which caused me some headache

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension for this at https://github.com/insilica/vscode-pycmd.  Install it from the vscode extensions view by searching for `pycmd`.

After installing, create a `Ctrl+Enter` hotkey for executing Python code in the active terminal. These are some reasonable settings for keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "extension.pycmd",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
}
```

pycmd uses the python abstract syntax tree to find the next complete expression following your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to do it without any extension.

Just want to mention that I had already [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
File need to be stored with`ps1` extension.

In `keybindings.json`, include:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname == .ps1"
    }
```

Having cursor in powershell script line and clicking `ctrl+enter` execute this line in active terminal window.