# Vscode run current line and go to next line or new line

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I am using Vscode for python programming. In spyder, there is a feature that if after running the current line, it will automatically go the next line. I configure my vscode according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404225/vs-code-move-to-next-line-on-run-ctrl-enter) and achieve that function.

However, one extra thing that I want is that when I run the last line of code, can it automatically new a line for me, instead of staying on the same line, i.e., the last line?

For example, as shown below
[image]

After I run the loop, can it automatically new a line for me?

Thanks a lo!

Comment: the majority of this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58404225/11107541. the part about creating a new line when the cursor is at the last line is currently not possible I think. There is no context key for that as far as I know, but I'd be happy to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same, found this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14695 which is still open at the moment.