# Running commands on VS Code multiple terminal setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I am using VS Code with multiple editors and multiple terminals. I ideally would like to run code in the terminal that is currently visible. Using the macros library by geddski I came close to a solution but could not figure out how to finalize the process.

settings.json

```
"macros": {  // Note: this requires macros extension by publisher:"geddski" 
"runSelectedInFocusedTerminal": [
"editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
"workbench.action.terminal.focus",
"workbench.action.terminal.paste",
"workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
"cursorDown"
]
}
```

keybindings.json

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "macros.runSelectedInFocusedTerminal",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python' && resourceExtname == '.py'"
}
```

This macro successfully copies the line or the selected text onto the terminal but it does not run it and go back to the visible editor as I would like.

I also have the <kbd>ctrl+enter</kbd> trick from this post: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404225/vs-code-move-to-next-line-on-run-ctrl-enter). However this runs the code in the first terminal I opened using this shortcut and not the visible terminal so it is not a viable solution for using terminals effectively on a multi terminal setup.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use the `Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal` command in the command palette or bind it to a keybinding? Ex. in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText"
}
```

Also note that VS Code 1.77 added the `runCommands` command for keyboard shortcuts, so you shouldn't need an extension to bind a sequence of commands to a keyboard shortcut anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using '**sendSequence**' instead of executing pasted code in terminal.

```
"macros": {
    "runSelectedInFocusedTerminal": [
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": {
                "text": "${clipboard}\n"
            }
        },
        "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "cursorDown"
    ]
}
```