# Prevent VSCode from skipping to next non empty line when executing current line with Shift+Enter in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, settings, interactive

I'm using VSCode extensively in my workflow together with the Vim extension.
I frequently execute single lines in the editor in Python interactive mode.
On Shift+Enter (with no characters highlighted) it is supposed to only execute the current line and not change the cursor position.

This behaviour changes sometimes and VSCode skips to the next non empty line in the editor after hitting Shift+Enter which hinders my desired workflow considerably.

This behaviour started showing up before, and a full reinstall fixed it. But now I did a full reinstall and Code still jumps the cursor to the next line on Shift+Enter.

Is there a way to prevent this and get the old behaviour persistently again?

My Keybindings and settings file look like this:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "shift+down",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
        "when": "terminal.active"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+up",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
    }
]
```

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
}
```

I tried completly reinstalling (uninstall vscode, remove all local folders in appdata). This fixed the problem before. On encountering the problem again, I was not able to revert to the desired cursor behaviour with this approach.

The only keyboard shortcut active in editor with shift+enter is Python Run Selection/Line in Python terminal. To use this command the Python extension has to be activated, all others are deactivated.

[Current keyboard shortucuts with shift+Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9t6a.png)

EDIT:

I found the solution with the help of the comments below:

The python extension version I was using was:
2023.20.0 which released about a two weeks ago.

Downgrading to 2023.18.0 fixed the problem. Apparently they added this feature per default but it would be nice to know how to deactivate without having to downgrade.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Include also the version of your Python extension. 3) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: 4) Are you sure it's not actually running the current _code cell_ and advancing the cursor to the _next code cell_? Because that's what's supposed to happen in interactive Python files (with `#%%` cell magics). It's the default `jupyter.runcurrentcelladvance` keybinding. In non-interactive Python files (without `#%%` cell magics), then it should just run the current line/selection in the terminal.

Comment: 5) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: please do not post answers in question posts. post answers as answer posts. also, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you're describing in your solution. I do not get the behaviour you describe in v2023.20.0 of the Python extension. Please edit your question post to provide the information I solicited from you in my five questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the **SmartSend** setting (at least for me).
To remove please do the following:

In the VS Code search bar at the top of the IDE search for:

```
settings.json
```

Click on the one that says:

```
Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)
```

Inside the opened 'settings.json' file paste the following:

```
{
    "python.REPL.enableREPLSmartSend": false
}
```

Voila!

Note: my Visual Studio Code version is 1.85.1

Answer (score 0):

Yep. This is a new change in [version 2023.20.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/v2023.20.0) of the Python extension.

In the release blogpost at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-november-2023-release/#improvements-to-shift-enter-run-line-in-terminal, they wrote:

> With our new experimental Smart Send feature, the Python extension will send the smallest runnable block of code surrounding the line where your cursor is to the REPL for execution. This ensures that only complete and executable sections of code are sent to the REPL. The cursor will also be automatically placed to the next executable line, to provide a smooth experience when executing multiple chunks iteratively.

It's also [mentioned in the VS Code 1.84 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_improvements-to-run-line-in-the-terminal)

You can disable Smart Send by setting the `python.REPL.enableREPLSmartSend` VS Code setting contributed by the Python extension to `false`.

The relevant issue ticket that tracked the addition of this feature is [Dynamic Smart Cursor Movement #21838](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21838).

Fun historical fact: This feature was [requested before and declined](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13495). Interesting that now that make it the default behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the **Keyboard Shortcuts** page and click the **Record Keys** button on the right

   [image]
2. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys
3. Find results that do not meet expectations and delete them

   [image]