# Execute python code from a script, line by line, in VScode and automatically jump to next command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Python with VS Code (with the relevant Python extensions installed). I often work in the way that, I have a Python script open, and in focus, and with Shift+Enter I send and execute the command in the open terminal below. Until this morning, it used to be that if the cursor was flashing at a given line, Shift+Enter would send the whole command for execution, even if it spanned multiple lines, and right afterwards the cursor would jump to the next command and wait.

I seem to have accidentally fiddled with something, however, and now Shift+Enter does execute but only one-line commands while the cursor remains on the same line afterwards. Multi-lines commands with not be executed with the shortcut, unless I explicitly select the all the lines I want to execute.

Any ideas of what setting I changed and how I can get back the previous functionality?

I believe this feature is the setting `python.execSelectionInTerminal`  from the Python extension for VS Code but I am not sure how I messed it up.

Comment: The extension itself might have changed without notice. You'd better get started from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Comment: check your smart send enabled setting. if you set it to `false`, then I'll probably close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77521304/11107541.

Comment: Yes @starball thank you! Made my day! Apologies for duplicate issue (did try to search though but apparently unsuccessfully)